# Feather and spells turning permanents in to Creatures

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

If I have [Feather, the Redeemed](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFeather%2c%20the%20Redeemed%5d) and I cast an Instant or Sorcery that turns a target permanent into a creature (Say [Siege of Towers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSiege%20of%20Towers%5d) for example) Will that trigger Feather's ability to return that to my hand?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not.

[Feather, the Redeemed](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFeather%2c%20the%20Redeemed%5d) triggers on *casting* a spell, which happens well before the spell would resolve and have any effect such as turning its target into a creature.

When you cast [Siege of Towers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSiege%20of%20Towers%5d), it is not targeting a creature you control; it is targeting a land you control. By the time the mountain becomes a creature, it is well past the chance for Feather, the Redeemed to trigger. Unless you are targeting a land that is also a creature.

Comment: However, if you have two copies of it, you can have the second one target the mountain that the first one turned into a creature, and replicate it onto a new mountain.

Comment: I think that’s covered by my last sentence.

Comment: My point is that if you replicate the spell, you just need the original to target a creature. The copies don't have to target a creature.

Comment: @Acccumulation Ah, I see, didn't notice that Siege of Towers had Replicate.